# Let $G :[c,d] \to\mathbb R$ , $x \to G(x)= \int_{\alpha(x)}^{\beta(x)}f(t)dt$ , proof that $G$ is derivable

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, definite-integrals

> Let $f: [a, b] \to\mathbb R$ be a continuous function and let $ α, β: [c, d] \to [a, b]$ be two derivable functions such that $α (x) ≤ β (x)$ for all $x \in [c , d]$. Let $G :[c,d] \to\mathbb R$ , $x \to G(x)= \int_{\alpha(x)}^{\beta(x)}f(t)dt$ , proof that $G$ is derivable, and that  $G'(x)= \beta'(x)f(\beta(x))−\alpha'(x)f(\alpha(x))$.

Any ideas to prove that proposition?

Comment: Try proving it for $G(x) = \int_a^x f(t)dt $ first and then use the chain rule.

Comment: Also, $\alpha(x)\le\beta(x)$ is unnecessary.

Comment: By "derivable" do you mean "differentiable"?

Comment: Yes, differentiable